# Windows DNS64 Server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, ipv6

As detailed [on the MS Q&A site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/505162/windows-dns-server-and-dns64.html) I have trouble implementing DNS64 on my Windows 2019 domain controllers / DNS servers. The PowerShell CmdLets run fine, but they don't do anything, I ran `Set-NetDnsTransitionConfiguration -PrefixMapping "2001:db8:cafe:64::/96,0.0.0.0/0" -State Enabled` and everything looks fine, but clients don't get AAAA records e.g. for azure.com and `Get-NetDnsTransitionMonitoring` shows 0s everywhere.
The PowerShell CmdLets are there, so I *assume* they are supposed to work. OTOH I recently found that on Windows that's not always the case :-(
An old post on TechNet (RIP) claimed that it worked on 2012R2, but the admin had DirectAccess installed. Which I normally wouldn't touch with a 10 foot pool, especially on a DC. But running BIND on my Linux routers is sub-optimal as well.
Are there no other Windows admins out there looking to go IPv6 native?

Comment: Yes, you have to have DirectAccess installed, but why do you insist on installing it on the domain controller? Most of the dinosaurs you're trying to communicate with probably can't even join the domain anyway.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I'm trying to go IPv6-native and the "dinosaurs" I'm trying to communicate with are out on the Internet, like StackExchange ;-) I have NAT64 on my router but you still need DNS64 and I've grown quite fond of the DNS Manager, also all my systems already use the DCs as DNS servers. So it would be nice to use them for DNS64 as well.

Comment: You keep saying "IPv6-native" but nothing prevents you from also using IPv4 to access sites on the Internet. Are you instead trying to set up an IPv6-_only_ network?! Most of us run dual stack.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, I mean IPv6-only. Getting tired of configuring everything twice... Right now I have configured 2 BIND servers as forwarders on my DCs and the idea is to go back to Windows DNS only.

Comment: I can see doing this as an experiment but we're probably at least 10 years away from this being a reasonable thing to do in most contexts. In the meantime you'll probably have to run NAT64/DNS64 on your DNS servers (not your DCs).

Comment: @MichaelHampton: My DCs are my DNS servers: replication and secure dynamic updates are nice things to have. And for the 10 years: why, oh lord, why?? I have 3 (cellular) internet connections and only get a single public IPv4. And _that_ terminates on a CPE which does not even do port forwarding. Promote IPv6, please :-)

Comment: I am promoting IPv6! I've been using it since 2006! I am also realistic about it. I know there are many people and companies out there who will wait as long as possible to move. Realistically we'll be doing dual stack for a very long time, at least in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, just to close this: I've decided to set up DNS64 using BIND servers on my Debian routers. It's easy and it works like a charm. Still a petty that Windows DNS does not seem to support DNS64. Otherwise Windows DNS is really nice and running DNS on my routers makes me feel quite uncomfortable...